# How to locate a path?

Tags: locate

Is it possible to `locate` a path in the file system like what can be done for file names? For example I want to find all paths in system that include 'foo/bar', which may have the following result:

> /home/myname/test/**foo/bar**/hello
>   /var/www/site/**foo/bar**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are unable to find the file with the below command then try `updatedb` for updating db used by locate command.

```
locate -r foot/bar/
```

or

```
# locate  "/*/bar/avi"
/foot/bar/avi
```

find command can also do this

`find / -path */foot/bar*`

`find /`  will search the whole system starting from `/`

Comment: `locate  "*/bar/avi"` gave me the fastest and the most accurate result.

Answer (score 3):

using `find` command,

```
find . -ipath "*foo/bar*"
```

or if you prefer regex syntax then you can use,

```
find . -iregex ".*foo/bar.*"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
ls -lR | sed -n 's/foo\/bar/p'
```

Possibly very long output, i d throw it directly in a file

```
ls -lR | sed -n 's/foo\/bar/p' >> outfile
```

Answer (score -2):

This should do what you want:

```
user@machine% find / -print0 | grep -FzZ 'foo/bar'
```

You'll get a lot of "permission denied" unless you run as root or are running it on your own home directory.

Comment: You can also redirect errors with `2>/dev/null`